# Can you add your application to the places bar in the OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, openfiledialog

I have noticed on Vista/7 that when the OpenFileDialog is used in some applications (e.g. MS Word, Visual Studio) it also contains the application itself in the places bar with a list of favourite folder locations which contains documents of the type supported. E.g.

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this for your own application, or does MS Word etc. use an extended version of the OpenFileDialog, meaning I need to extend the OpenFileDialog/write my own to add this functionality?

Comment: The IFileDialog::AddPlace() method.  No, that's not easy to do.  The Windows API Code Pack has a wrapper for this, CommonFileDialog.AddPlace() method.